# Jigo's letter in Mononoke Hime

Tags: mononoke-hime

In Miyazaki movie "Mononoke Hime" Lady Eboshi, leader of Irontown, receives a letter from Jigo's, alledgedly from the emperor. To me, it was not clear why she decided to go along with Jigo's plan of killing the Forest Spirit.

I understand it was her desire to keep cutting down the forest, and then it would be convenient for her, but the appearance of Jigo's being a trigger for her to take such a step is not clear to me. Was she promised peace, that men of his group wouldn't attack Irontown? Was she promised gold? What Lady Eboshi expected to win by cutting down the head of the Forest Spirit?

When I first watched that scene, it seemed to be it would be a letter from the emperor communicating he would not take possession of Irontown in exchange for the God's head, but now I read that the emperor wouldn't have any political power at the time the story apparentely takes place.